# Rails Submit Buttons Not working (name="commit")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a Rails 5 application using only AngularJS, no jQuery/Turbolinks.  Typical submit buttons generated by form helper do not work in this application (go immediately to disabled) without submitting the form, and I've resorted to using button_tags with type="Submit" instead.

If I remove the "name='commit'" atribute from the submit button, it works as expected by submittin the form.  I'm wondering if there's something bound to this attribute that I'm not seeing.  Below is an example form.

```
<%= form_for(role) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>         <!-- this fails -->
    <input type="submit" /> <!-- this works -->
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Before click, the button html looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Role" data-disable-with="Update Role">
```

After click, the button looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Role" data-disable-with="Update Role" disabled="disabled" class="disabled">
```

It's as if Chrome thinks that the form has been submitted, but something has blocked this from happening.

Comment: As an update to this, I went to debugin Firefox, and the form helper buton works as expected.  Perhaps I have a Chrome extension that is a hinderance.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: [Link](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit)

```
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Commit", name: "commit" %> 
    #or
    <input type="submit" name="Commit" /> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Both of these configurations is failing to submit the form.  Only removing the name="commit" attribute has proven successful in testing.

Comment: @Csizzle do u have any js lines that belongs to the form. Cuz, smth missing in the post

Comment: There shouldn't be any JS associated with the form, as it's a plain form generated from scaffolding.  Is there a reason to think something may be missing?

Comment: @Csizzle if its just scaffolded, then its supposed to be `form_for(@role)` not  `form_for(role)`. I think, yr missing smth in the post to show us.

Comment: Scaffolding generated an edit.html.erb file with `<%= render 'form', role: @role %>`, which explains the local vs instance scope.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit) suggests, this is perfectly fine.

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Rails form_for will transform `f.submit` to the respective submit button with type as submit. Try restarting the server once and check if the issue persists.

An additional thing is that any button with type as `submit` inside the rails form will be taken as form submit button.

Comment: Restarting the server was unsuccessful.  The workaround I've been using is to convert <input> tags to <button> tags, but this is tedious when dealing with scaffolded views.